# Error adding dependencies for Firebase

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

when I add firebase libraries to android studio I get error:
[image]

I've successfully downloaded google-service.json file and placed it correctly, the error appeared when adding the libraries

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to allsub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my app level dependency

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.omarr.fireapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',     {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compie 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

please help me out
also please suggest topics I should be familiar with to be able to work these errors myself in the future.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in `compie 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'`

It must be **compile** instead of **compie**. Correct statement is:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
```

Comment: thanks a lot, yer another error appeared..
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0 ..

any suggestion

Comment: maybe internet connectivity issue. Try adding with firebase assistant with active internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo:

Use:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
```

instead of:

```
compie 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
```

Also add the google maven repo:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still got an error..
could not find method maven() for arguments...bla bla

Comment: Where did you add this code? Just add the maven repo in your top level file in the allprojects block